# Grep contains 'this' but can't contain 'this' into a file

Tags: grep

I'm currently working on a homework assignment and it is basically saying, "Find the single line with "Ju" but does not contain the letter "w" in that line"

I believe that I have to use grep. However I'm not sure if I can just add this to a file.

```
grep "Ju" | grep -v "w"
```

maybe?

```
grep "alpha" | grep -v "beta" > file-name
```

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens? (Looking at it, it's much more likely to do what you want than to make your computer explode ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is right, just add to it the filename

```
grep "Ju" file.txt | grep -v "w"
```

Answering your comment, grep doesn't change files.

Comment: Yes, you may replace '>' with '>>' if you don't want to overwrite the file (newfile.txt)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
grep '^[^w]*Ju[^w]*$' file.txt
```

- `^` and `$` denote start and end of the line respectively
- `[^w]*` matches everything excepts character `w`

So the above Regex necessary matches `Ju` in the line and make sure that the line does not contain `w` (`[^w]*`).